# java applet requestFocus() method error when called in js

Tags: java, javascript, html, applet, onload

I have error with calling `requestFocus()` method in JS.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLAppletElement> has no method 'requestFocus'
```

This is my JS code between `<head>` tags

```js
function onLoad() {
    var attributes = {
        'id': 'Client',
        'archive': 'client.jar',
        'code': 'org.kuzy.client.ui.Applet.class',
        'width': '100%',
        'height': '100%'
    };

    var parameters = {
        'scriptable': 'true'
    };

    deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters);

    window.onfocus = function() {
        document.getElementById("Client").requestFocus();
    };
}
```

There is one strange feature, when I run the code in debug in chrome, everything works fine.
I hope for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, but probably when you invokes the method requestFocus() applet is not already loaded. Probably when you are debugging you are stopping js execution and you are giving enough time to the applet to be loaded. So probably you need a callback or some mechanism in order to know when applet is ready.

Comment: *"..need a callback or some mechanism in order to know when applet is ready."*  Yes, exactly.  +1

Comment: Solution is found. I use function `setInterval()` that checks the applet status of each second.

Answer (score 0):

This entire method has a 'bad code' smell to it.

1. The `deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters);` call should be in the page body, and called as soon as the page is written.
2. The `function onLoad()` though, should logically be defined in the document head.
3. By the time of the `onLoad` call, the applet should at least be ***loading***, and might even be loaded ready for use.  Note that the `onload` event is fired when the page, the scripts, styles and images are downloaded.  But it does *not* cover downloads that are handled by the JVM (e.g. the Jars of the applet or its media resources).

Comment: The problem is that every time we run a html page that contains an applet, Java plug-in displays a dialog box to confirm run the applet, but in parallel with this html page continues to load until the user gives permission, the applet will not load and reference to applet will be null.

Comment: All the more reason to poll for the applet as suggested in the [first answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21823746/418556)!